# How to track the position of one of the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have Torpedoes and  Asteroids classes and in each class I floated their xPosition yPosition, height and width (both of them are ellipse). And then I created two ArrayLists in the main page.

I want to track the score, and when Torpedoes hit the Asteroids, the score will -1.

Before, I always used the method that

```java
if(yPosA - height/2 < yPosT < yPosA - height/2 || xPosA - width/2 <xPosT < xPosA +width/2) {
   score = score -1;
}
```

I also know how to do it with one ArrayList:

```java
for(Torpedoes theTorpedo: TorpedoList) {
   //compare the xPos and yPos with Asteroid( which I just create once, not a ArrayList)
}
```

However, I don't know how to compare their xPos if they are both in the ArrayList.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest the loops.

```
for(Torpedoes theTorpedo: TorpedoList) { 
  for(Asteroid theAsteroid: AsteroidList) { 
    //compare the pos of theTorpedo with theAsteroid
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can track the the score when now!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `HashMap<Projectiles>` to track objects at a specific location. For each torpedo in your `ArrayList<Torpedo>`, verify that the location it is moving into is unoccupied.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just started to learn Java and I haven't learned how to use HashMap<Projectiles> yet. Can you tell me more about it?